# Scrolling to a given control inside a WPF ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a scrollviewer that contains many user controls. When some internal events are raised in my code, I would like to focus the attention of the user to a given control.

Does anyone know a solution to scroll to a given control in the scrollviewer?

In the example below, I would like to scroll down to the control "Produit" by code-behind.

```
<ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<view:MyCustomTextBoxCtrl Title="NUMERO"/>
<view:MyCustomTextBoxCtrl Title="DATE" />
<view:MyCustomComboBox Title="OBJET" />
<view:MyCustomComboBox Title="AUTEUR" />
<view:MyCustomComboBox Title="TYPE" />
<view:MyCustomComboBox Title="PRODUIT" />
<view:MyCustomComboBox Title="THEME" />
...
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thx

Comment: You need [`BringIntoView` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Gotta love how the example code in that MSDN link doesn't actually use the method it's supposed to be an example of.